# Rails where having query

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, activerecord, join, where-clause

Here's the query I'm trying to run:

```
Stack.joins(:services)
     .select('stacks.id, stacks.name, count(services.id) as services_count')
     .group('stacks.id').having('services_count > 2')
```

The error I'm getting is:

> ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: PG::UndefinedColumn: ERROR:  column "services_count" does not exist
>   LINE 1: ...ack_items"."service_id" GROUP BY stacks.id HAVING services_c...

---

Here are how my Stack model is related:

```
class Stack < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :services, through: :stack_items
end

class StackItem < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :service
  belongs_to :stack
end

class Service < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :stacks, through: :stack_items, dependent: :destroy    
end
```

---

I just want to get a collection of `Stacks` that have at least 3 stack items where `service.weight == 1`.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Aliases that you set in the `SELECT` list in Postgres are not available in a `group by` clause, so simply change `.having('services_count > 2')` to `.having('count(services.id) > 2')`.

Comment: Is there a way to filter to only count services where the `service.layer == 1`?

Comment: @Serg for that you'll want to write your own join fragment `joins('inner join services on services.stack_id = stacks.id and servers.layer = 1`)`